# expression to transform unicode codepoint to character

Tags: vim, unicode

I've got a file that has escaped unicode in it:

```
blah blah blah \u2192 blah blah blah
```

I'd like to transform the unicode escapes into actual characters with a search/replace:

```
:%s/\\u\(\d\{4}\)/\=CodePointToCharacter(submatch(1))/g
```

Though I know how to transform a codepoint to a character in insert mode (`CTRL-V u 2192` for →), I don't know how to do the transformation in a vimL expression.

Do I need to write a custom function, or is there a builtin or plugin I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can first use `str2nr()` to convert the number from HEX, then use `nr2char` to display the char.

extend your command a little bit:

```
%s/\\u\(\x\{4}\)/\=nr2char(str2nr(submatch(1),16))/g
```

Comment: You beat me to it! Note that for hex matching, you need to replace `\d` with `\x`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat thank you, you are right, I didn't do much check on the first part of `:s`. updated.